# unable to run slide.js within a revealed div

Tags: jquery, swipe, hidden

I have settup where, upon clicking on a link, a hidden overlay div reveals itself, and within that is a div which allows the user to swipe between images.

I am using swipe.js for this purpose.

The problem im having is that the jQuery for the swipe.js is not working once being placed inside the hidden div, despite working when seperate from it.

here is a rough jsfiddle of what i have so far, you mouseover the image, click "view deatails" and then it shows the swipe (in jsfiddle you may need to resive the viewing window to see the images for some reason). as you can see the navigation does not mover between images.

http://jsfiddle.net/3uz45899/2/

here is the jQuery I have for the swipe

```
$(document).ready(function () {
Slider = $('#slider').Swipe({
    auto: 3000,
    continuous: true
}).data('Swipe');

$('.next').on('click', Slider.next);
$('.prev').on('click', Slider.prev);
});
```

and here is for revealing/concealing the div

```
$('.lbwrap.1').hover(function () {
$('.over.1').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}, function () {
$('.over.1').stop(true, true).fadeOut(700);
});
$('.lbwrap.2').hover(function () {
$('.over.2').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}, function () {
$('.over.2').stop(true, true).fadeOut(700);
});

$('.whitescreen').click(function () {
$('.detailsoverlay').toggle(true, true).fadeIn();
});


$('.closeoverlay').click(function () {
$('.detailsoverlay').toggle(true, true).fadeOut(700);
});
```

ive tried putting them in different orders, is something in there interfering with the swipe jquery?

here is a link of what the swipe part should look like
http://demo.hongkiat.com/jquery-swipejs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the slider function only works on visible elements.

Try you can initialize it when the slider appears. Like in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3uz45899/3/)

Just moved the code from `$(document).ready(function () {` to here:

```
$('.whitescreen').click(function () {
  $('.detailsoverlay').toggle(true, true).fadeIn();
  Slider = $('#slider').Swipe({
    auto: 3000,
    continuous: true
  }).data('Swipe');

  $('.next').on('click', Slider.next);
  $('.prev').on('click', Slider.prev);    
});
```

You only must add some function, that it doesn´t initialize twice for the same gallery.